# Can I use the same Apple ID from my iPod for my iPhone?

Tags: apple-id, iphone

I just got the iPhone 6 and I had the iPod 5. Would I be able to use the same ID for both so every thing is transferred on to there?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the same Apple ID, do not create a new one. The Apple ID is what 'ID's' you to the Apple system, allows backups, preferences, purchases, etc to be sync'd between devices. If you create a new Apple ID, you will lose all your purchases, etc.

You **can** use a different Apple ID for the App store than your Messages, iCloud, backups etc. Before Family share, you could have an Apple ID that was shared with your Family for purchases (everyone got access to the app or song), while maintaining different, personal Apple IDs for Messages, iCloud etc. However, with Family Share, you do not need to do this, as Family share allows you to include personal Apple IDs in a purchasing 'group'.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @cmmason above explained Apple ID very well, but if you want to transfer *everything* over to your iPhone 6, then follow these steps:

1. Connect iPod Touch to computer with iTunes on it
2. Click the iPod Touch in the top left
3. Cancel automatic backup, if you have that enabled
4. Check Encrypt Backup
5. Click Backup Now, and yes, you wish to copy whatever apps that are not in your iTunes library into your library.
6. After the backup is complete, unplug your iPod from your computer and plug your iPhone 6 in.
7. Click the iPhone in the top left of the window
8. Click Restore Backup and select the backup of your iPod that you just made.